# Active Directory (AD) authentication Spring-Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, active-directory

Active directory is very new to me can someone help me to setup `WebSecurityConfig` for having the authentication with AD correctly with Spring Security.

The AD is like:

```
CN=myCN,OU=OU_1,OU=OU_2,DC=example,DC=com
```

I am using this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/ and I have the `configure` method like (it is kotlin code):

```java
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun configure(auth: AuthenticationManagerBuilder) {
        auth
                .ldapAuthentication()
                .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=OU_1,ou=OU_2")
                .groupSearchBase("")
                .userSearchFilter("CN=myCN")
                .contextSource()
                .url("ldap://{targeted AD IP:389}/dc=example,dc=com")
                .and()
                .passwordCompare()
                .passwordEncoder(LdapShaPasswordEncoder())
                .passwordAttribute("userPassword")
    }
```

The problem is that I cannot authenticate with this code. The error message I get is:

```
Failed to bind as uid=username,CN=myCN,OU=OU_1, OU=OU_2: org.springframework.ldap.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090400, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1]; nested exception is javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090400, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1]
```

I am sure that the user exist and the credential I am using is correct.

Comment: Could you please add more information on the actual problem?

Comment: I added the error to the question.